# PHP Json API server not working

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I am trying to test client server with php and json. I am trying curl json request to an api url, and its seems it works.

Here is client code :

```
$data = array('id' => 2, 'something' => 4);
$content = json_encode($data);

$url = 'http://localhost/json.api.php'; 
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 

$result     = curl_exec($curl);
$response   = json_decode($result);
echo "<pre>"; 
var_dump($response);
curl_close($curl);
```

But, how can i get this request on server (on json.api.php) and parse it do something and then return json to requester client.

Comment: I don't understand, the problem is creating the client? creating the server? using the data from server in the client?

Comment: No, client is ok, but how can i get json on server which came from client ? In more detail, how you will parse on your server if i made request as shown on above example ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` to get the request